# How to generate an APNS authorization token using a .p8 file in Swift?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use APNS to do device-to-device communication. I have the code working, except the authorization token has to be created using a shell script based on Apple's "[Sending push notifications using command-line tools](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools)"

After creating the token from the Terminal, I copy/paste that token string into the POST request as a value of the "authorization" key from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) and the APNS message works perfectly.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to use the .p8 file and profile to create the authorization token using Swift. Apple's command-line page uses openssl which I'm hesitant to use in my project unless I know for sure that there isn't an easier solution because I'd like the app to be used in other countries.

Has anyone written Swift code to create an APNS authorization token based on a .p8 file and profile? If so, was it done with openssl?

One other side-question: if there's a way to use AWS or Firebase for device-to-device APNS, please post a link to the documentation on how to do it here. I hit a brick wall with that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem with the .p8 file and openssl, but I was able to use Google FCM to send APNS messages to another iOS and iPad device.